# CocoaLumberjack: timed out while trying to read CoreDataLogger.xcodeproj

Tags: carthage, cocoalumberjack

I'm using Carthage, Xcode 8 and swift 2.3, on Mac Sierra, carthage version 0.17.2

In my cartfile I have: github "CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack" "2.4.0"

I run Carthage bootstrap --platform iOS and I get this error:
timed out while trying to read CoreDataLogger.xcodeproj

Any suggestions on what I can do as I'm stuck at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  Need to be be running at least Carthage 0.18.1 for Xcode 8 support.  I was on Carthage 0.17.2